# How can I modify NSMutableArray property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I use 2 sqlite db files.

1) fill items from A sqlite db.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
```

.......

```
FMResultSet *results = [db1 executeQuery:query];

    while ([results next]) {

        Book *book = [[Book alloc] init];

        book.content = [results stringForColumn:@"Zcontent"];
        book.title   = [results stringForColumn:@"Ztitle"];
        book.idx     = [results intForColumn:@"Zidx"];

        book.highlight_YN  = NO;

        [items addObject:book];
        [book release];
    }
```

2) After then, select items from other -B- sqlite db.

```
FMDatabase *userDB = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:userfmdbPath];  
NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT zidx, highlight_YN FROM zHighlight where zbook = %d and zchapter = %d order by zidx ", pBook,pChapter];

FMResultSet *userresults = [userDB executeQuery:query2];
```

3) Question : I want to modify property(`highlight_YN`) of items with results of `userresults` compared with `results` - `zidx` .

How can I modify `NSMutableArray` property?

Comment: I don't see NSMutableArray in your code up there.  In fact, I see all sorts of problems (like where does the `bible` in `[items addObject:bible]` come from?). Please modify your question to clean up your code and bring in a NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann Sorry! I left out some code. Thanks!! My question is edited. ^^*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `items` array and search for the object.

```
    for ( Book *book in items ) {
        if( book.idx == [userresults intForColumn:@"zidx"] )
        {
            book.highlight_YN = [userresults boolForColumn:@"highlight_YN"];
            break;
        }
    }
```